# Creating a table name for line item CPQ Quote template

Tags: cpq, quote-template

I want to give my line item tables a name on the Quote template in Salesforce CPQ. For example let's say I have 2 tables, Products and members, I did create template sections and content, however I'm unable to display a table name like Table 1 : Product Listings (or) Table 2 : Member listing to appear above each of these tables. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you could

1. Add a section to your template immediately above the Line Items section
2. Create an HTML content record that includes the table header and link it to the section

You might have to play around with this a little to get alignment and spacing correct, but it should work.